# Blade in laravel 4.2 not working in @elseif statement

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to render my javascript codes using blade template in **Laravel 4.2** and unable to render inside **@elseif** but is working in **@if statement**. Can anyone verify this is a flaw in Laravel 4.2 or it is an error.

```
@if ( $page == 'loginpage' )
    @yield('body') 
    {{ HTML::script('js/jquery.min.js') }} //works here
@elseif ( $page == 'resetpage' )
    @include('panel')
    @yield ('body')
    @section('js')
    {{ HTML::script('js/jquery.min.js') }} //cannot render from here neither from the yielded section.
    @show
@endif
```

Only the HTML::script in @if statement works. Any help is granted. Thanks in advance.

Edit:
**Solved** the problem as i have overrided the section with some other sections. Sorry to bother you all.

Comment: Isn't it `@section('js') ... @stop`?

Comment: @lukasgeiter As per [laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates) , for defining the section we use show and to override or add data in section we use `@stop`

Comment: True I forgot about that...